# How to read Postgres SQL data into Grafana graph

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, grafana

I want Grafana to read the Postgres SQL data to plot the graph.  Can anybody share some links or information about how to do the export of data from postgres to Grafana.

This information would be useful for plotting the real time graph for my application debugging.

Comment: I'm using `Sensu` to transfer `Postgres Metric` to Grafana https://github.com/sensu-plugins/sensu-plugins-postgres. However, I never try to push `Postgres Metric` directly to Grafana.

Comment: Did you find the way how to represent PostgreSQL data on Grafana?

Answer (score 6):

Support for Postgres have been added to Grafana v4.6.0-beta1.

You can download it from https://grafana.com/grafana/download/4.6.0-beta1

Comment: for the readers from future, the mentioned pull request is merged now.

Comment: This PR have been merged to master. We will release v4.6.0-beta1 today with support for postgres.